# Sql Optimization order by clause

Tags: mysql

I am executing a MySQL query like this example:

```
SELECT prodname from products WHERE prod_price = 100 OR prod_price = 200;
```

The result which I get is as

```
prodname
product1
product2
```

but `product1` corresponds to `prod_price = 200` and `product2` corresponds to `prod_price = 100`.

Is there any way we can print the `prodname` in order of `prod_price` given in where clause?

For example, I want output as:

```
prodname
product2
product1
```

I dont want to output `prod_price` with it, only `prodname` as an output is required.

Answer (score 0):

yes, ORDER BY can order results even on columns that are not returned.  The mysql engine will have to look them up, mind you, and internally there is additional data traffic (ie, might not be able to use the same index)

```
... ORDER BY prod_price ASC
```